# Flexbox does not trigger click event

Tags: jquery

You can check the demo at

http://demo.m.moneylife.in/events/advisor2/pricing/

Clicking on next button works fine but when you click on previous edit. It does not work to get the element active
class.

I have just added an alert to check

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("button.previous").each(function(e) {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            alert(90);
        });
    });
    $("button.next").each(function(e) {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().next("li").addClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("previous");
            $(this).html('<img src="images/edit.svg" />');
            $(this).addClass("collapsed");
            $(this).removeClass("next");
            $(this).parent().addClass("entered");
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().next("li").addClass("complete");
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pricing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pricing.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
    3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pricing.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="first active">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
            <li class="second">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
            <li class="third">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
            <li class="fourth">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
            <li class="fifth">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
            <li class="sixth">
                <input type="button" name="" class="next" value="next" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: @karthick kindly check and let me know

Comment: Kindly suggest an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to all buttons with a `previous` class when you load the document. At that point there are none. Adding the class later will not bind them. You should change your `previous` binding to a function and call that when your `next` buttons are clicked.

Untested code:

```
function doBinding(){
    $('button.previous').each(function(e){ 
        $(this).click(function(e){
            alert(90);
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(e){   
    $('button.next').each(function(e){ 
        $(this).click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().next('li').addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('previous');
        $(this).html('<img src="images/edit.svg"/>')
        $(this).addClass('collapsed')
        $(this).removeClass('next');
        $(this).parent().addClass('entered')
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().next('li').addClass('complete');
        doBinding();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share an example

Comment: There was an extra bracket that I've removed. Could you provide more details than "does not work"?